# How can I put two integers next to each other?

Tags: multidimensional-array, number-formatting

Suppose that we have two 2-d arrays. I want to read each member of the first array and returns two numbers next to each other, first, the column number and second the exact number that the program read from the first array. For example, if the first array is:
    **A= {1 2 3}

       {4 5 6}

       {7 8 9}**
I expected to return
    **B={11 22 33}
    {14 25 36}
    {17 28 39}**.
The problem is that when I want to put column index number and exact number next to each other, I have error. Another thing is that I need this output as input of another code and it means the output should be number not string. Thanks in advance.

```
for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
   for (int j=0;j<3;j++){   
      B[i][j]= jA[i][j];
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't even want to conceive of imagining to think about how this other system is written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i=0; i<3;i++){
   for (int j=0; j<3; j++){   
      B[i][j] = 10*(j+1) + A[i][j];
   }
}
```

Note: if you have two-digit values in A, then do 100* instead of 10*, or if three-digit values, then 1000*, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to add the index multiplied by 10. So something like (in psuedo-code):

```
int arr1 = {1 2 3} {4 5 6} {7 8 9};
int arr2;

for (int i=0;i<arr1.length;i++){
  for (int j=0; j<arr1[i].length;j++){
     arr2[i][j] = ((j+1)*10) + arr1[i][j];
  }
}

return arr2
```

This will only work if the array is restricted to numbers 0 through 9.

Comment: This works as long as the contents of the array are in [0,9].

Comment: Indeed, I should have put that assumption.

Comment: It will only take positive numbers too.  I didn't think about that either and edited my comment afterwards